# single row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

Create Inventory table(salesno,salesname,branch,salesamount). Insert 5 records.

The aim is to carry out this task in one command!
Delete the tuples where average salesamount <1000.

I have added 2 entries with sales amount as 900 & 1000 under the same branch. I have to get these deleted.

The command I tried is

```
DELETE inventory WHERE (SELECT avg(salesamount) FROM inventory GROUP BY branch) < 1000;
```

This returns an error saying "single row subquery returns more than one row"?

How do I go about this error?

Here's the data:
SQL> SELECT * FROM inventory;

```
SALESNO SALESNAME  BRANCH  SALESAMOUNT
------- ---------- ------- -----------
     1          A    Sales         900
     2          B    Sales        1000
     3          C       HR        5000
     4          D       HR        6000
     5          E  Finance        8000
```

Comment: How many branches do you have?

Comment: 3 branches. 2 entries are under the same branch.

Comment: Post the results of your select statement:                                    (SELECT avg(salesamount) FROM inventory GROUP BY branch) < 1000;       this will let us know the exact problem

Comment: Its been answered by pobrelkey!

Comment: try select salesamount from inventory where salesamount < 1000, don't delete, just to see, what are values getting returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM inventory WHERE branch IN (SELECT branch FROM inventory GROUP BY branch HAVING AVG(salesamount) < 1000)
```